# Wordpress Loop Post Counter

Tags: php, wordpress

This code adds a unique class to every first/second/third multiple in the Wordpress loop:

```
<?php
$style_classes = array('first','second','third');
$style_index = 0;

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div <?php $k = $style_index%3; echo "class=post&nbsp;$style_classes[$k]"; $style_index++; ?>>test</div>
```

So the first post has a class of first, the second a class of second, the third a class of third, and then it resets with the fourth post having a class of first, the fifth post a class of second, etc etc.

Is there a way to also make only the first three posts have an additional class called "special"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not compress together so much code into one line.

Instead, make one statement per line, that keeps you flexible to add stuff, like your special class:

```
<?php
$style_classes = array('first','second','third');
$style_index = 0;

if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : 
        the_post();
        $style_index = $wp_query->current_post;
        $classes = array('post');
        $classes[] = $style_classes[$style_index % 3];
        if ($style_index < 3) $classes[] = 'special'
        $class = sprintf('class="%s"', implode(' ', $classes));
?>
<div <?php echo $class?>>test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code and the tip. It does exactly what is needed and is organized beyond any level I could have implemented. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one if statement to your code like this -

```
<div>
   <?php 
      $k = $style_index%3; 
      if ($style_index < 3) $special = "special";
      else $special = "";
      echo "class=post&nbsp;$style_classes[$k] $special"; 
      $style_index++; 
   ?>
test
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, appreciate it.



I try adding that, but it's adding the special class to every post. Here's my code:

`<div 
    <?php 
      $k = $style_index%3; 
      if ($style_index < 3) $special = "special";
      else $special;
      echo "class=post&nbsp;$style_classes[$k]$special"; 
      $style_index++; 
    ?>
>test</div>`